# How to use datapicker in Ruby on Rails using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails application, and I want to use HTML `textbox` as a `datepicker` on it like below:

```
<div class='row' style="font-size:small">
    <span class='label'>
         <Label for="Lbl_DateTime" ForeColor="#FF3300">Requested Date/Time</Label>
               </span>
    <span class='formw'>
         <input type="text" Name="TxtBx_DateTime" id="reqesteddate" class="hajanDatePicker" />
    </span>
</div>
```

and below is the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#reqesteddate").datepicker({
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        //buttonImage: 'calendar.jpg',
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    }); 
</script>
```

But when I click on the html `textbox` it not show me the calendar. Why?
Kindly help me, waiting for reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know, you don't need `jquery` for datepicker. You can use `datetime-local` `input` type in HTML and can have inbuilt features.

Comment: Datepicker comes with jQuery UI. Have you included it in your layout?

Comment: No I do not include any `jquery UI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to resolve this problem